# how to create functions inside functions using prototypes in javaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just want to create functions inside function can be accessed in the following format(like the one in jquery):
`mainFunction().childFunction();`
I think this can be achieved using prototypes, but i am not sure how to do this.Thank you.

Comment: Your highlighted line could simply be a function that returns an object, which has a key of `childFunction` on it that is a function.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22541712/create-method-inside-function

Comment: Study some tutorials. Stackoverflow is not a tutorial service. The web is full of learning resources. See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: actually i am trying something like `funOne().funTwo()` not `objectOne.functionOne()`.Like it is in jQuery `$("selector").ready()`.thank you.

Comment: The point is that the second function is being called off of an object, be that object exist outside a function, or be returned from a function and the call chained, you are calling the second function off of some object.  Where it comes from is a smaller detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mainFunction` needs to return something that has a `childFunction()`. The dot simply accesses a property on the returned value. For example:

```js
function mainFunction() {
  console.log('mainCalled')
  return {
    childFunction() {
      console.log("childCalled")
      return this
    },
    someOtherFunction() {
      console.log("someother called")
      return this
    }
  }
}

mainFunction().childFunction()
mainFunction().someOtherFunction()
mainFunction().childFunction().someOtherFunction()
```

Comment: _thank you_ it helped a lot but this is only working for one function for example i want to have more than one function in `mainFunction()`,like if i want `mainFunction().one();mainFunction().two();` and upto `mainFunction().n()` what can i do.

Comment: the returned object from the mainFunction would need to contain any method you want to be able to call chained off of the call to the mainFunction.

Comment: as i am student i can't understand what you are trying to say please just give and block of code then i may understand, and thank you for your interest.

Comment: @Taplar is correct — the object just needs more properties, see updated code for example.

Comment: If you look at the answer, the method is returning `{ childFunction() {} }` which is effectively creating `{ childFunction: function () {} }` which is an object with a single key of `childFunction`, which has a value of a function that can be invoked.  If you want more functions to be available, just like any other javascript object, you can add additional key value pairs by separating them by commas.  `{ thing1: value1, thing2: value2 }`  The values in this case being function definitions.

Comment: okay, thank you but i can't understand that what return is returning is it a array or an object.What is it called?

Comment: The main function is returning an object. That's what the `{}` mean.

Comment: It's an object.  `{}` in javascript denotes an object definition, which is an element with key value pairs.  An array in javascript is denoted by `[]` and has keys which are numerical and reflect an index in the array.

Comment: no i thought it is an array because in objects they are something like`{property:sasa,propertyTwo:ssgsgwf}` but is like a mixture of array and object.

Comment: can anyone tell me why we are not using function keyword for all the functions we are returning in the object.

Answer (score 0):

Chainable functions only need to be aware of its context of definition in order to be chainable. I must disagree with the approved answer. If you need to chain several functions and each function must return a scope with multiple methods that also need to be chainable, you’ll end up with a very hard to read piece of code or a  so called spaghetti code.

So a simple solution is that all functions defined to be chainable share the scope of definition and then each of those functions return the context of definition or scope. The context of definition could be anything, from `window` itself to an object or even a function.

```
var context = this;

function foo() {
   // some code execution
   return context;
}

function bar() {
    // some code execution
    return context;
}

function baz() {
    // some code execution
    return context;
}

// chained together 
foo().bar().baz();
```

The result is the same, but with this approach you’ll end up with cleaner and more maintainable code.

Hope a different point of view could help too.