# How to make a function in a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, function, typeerror

I am somewhat new to Javascript, and I am trying to make a library for myself, so I dont have to code it in later. I have this code (below).

```
function lib() {
  let _this = this;
  this.addstring= (n, d) => {
    return n + d
  }
}
console.log(lib.addstring("foo", "bar"))
```

When the code above is ran, it tells me that `lib.addstring` is not a function. How would I be able to write this as a function?

###### question answered by @traynor in comments

Comment: Replace this.add... with lib.add... However, this would only make sense if the function was called first. You could create an IIFE from the function.

Comment: [Create method inside function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22541712/create-method-inside-function), [How do you create a method for a custom object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504803/how-do-you-create-a-method-for-a-custom-object-in-javascript)

Comment: @traynor oh... I did not realize that this had already been answered. It was hard for me to search for a post because I did not really know what this would be called. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You are using this incorrectly. You do not create lib instance, so you don't need `this`. If you wish to group everything on `lib` object, just wrap everything to the object:

```js
const lib = {
  addstring(n, d) {
    return n + d
  }
}

console.log(lib.addstring("foo", "bar"))
```

Comment: This is already what I have, I dont want it to be a variable object. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 2):

A nice way to do this would be ES6 modules. With ES6 modules, you would create a new file that uses the `export` keyword for every function you want to use externally. Here's an example:

library.mjs

```
export function addstring(n, d) {
  return n + d;
}
```

code.js

```
import {addstring} from './library.mjs';

console.log(addstring("foo", "bar"))
```

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful, but I accidentally forgot to mention I was using Node and not ES6.

Comment: Node.js supports ES6. ES6 is just a newer version of the javascript specification. All recent versions of major browsers and node.js support it.

Comment: The problem is, I'm not using Node in a browser environment... if i go into the package.json and change it, none of my other functions will work. It's just my terrible code setup

Comment: If you're not using not in a browser environment, it will still support ES6 modules, you just need to add `"type": "module"` in your package.json. Sorry if I didn't have that clear in my answer.